# How to convert string from redis cache to json array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, redis

I received this
"s:13:"{"foo":"bar"}";"

instead of this
{
[
"foo":"bar"
],
}

Comment: btw both are wrong json. if you are use  official cache by laravel you should get array instead json

Comment: Redis is a simple key-value store. What you get is what you stored in it to begin with so maybe take a look at how you store things rather at how they are retrieved.

Comment: the json array is serialize to be able to save it as a string in redis because redis can't accept array to store

Comment: Yes of course it is serialized to be stored. However the serialisation says that what is stored is a string ("s:13" means string of length 13) if you wanted to get it back as an array then serialize the array directly to put it in the store. It's not clear what the problem is here without any actual code. If you used the redis `Cache` facade then all this would be taken care of for you by Laravel